# Range-based-for implementation compiles in g++ but not in clang++

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, clang

*The following range-based-for snippet compiles fine in g++ 4.6.1, but not with clang++ version 3.1 (trunk 151577) on oneiric amd64.*

A very basic range-based for (eg std::vector) seems to work fine, so something is wrong with my implementation for my own enumerations.

**I am looking for a sanity-check or a work-around.**

If someone has a work-around for range-based-for that clang++ is happy with, that would be fantastic.

```
template< typename E >
class Enum
{
public:
    Enum() : m_e( E::Last ) { }
    Enum( E t ) : m_e( t ) { }
    E operator()() const
    {
        return m_e;
    }

public: 
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator( int val ) : m_val( val )    { }
        E operator*( void ) const
        {
            return (E) m_val;
        }
        void operator++( void )
        {
            ++m_val;
        }
        bool operator!=( Iterator rhs ) const
        {
            return m_val != rhs.m_val;
        }
    private:
        int  m_val;
    };
private:
    E m_e;
};

enum class eCOLORS
{
    kBLUE=0, kGREEN, kRED, kPURPLE,
    First=kBLUE, Last=kPURPLE
};

Enum<eCOLORS>::Iterator begin(const Enum<eCOLORS>& b)
{
    return Enum<eCOLORS>::Iterator( (int)(eCOLORS::First ));
}

Enum<eCOLORS>::Iterator end(const Enum<eCOLORS>& b)
{
    return Enum<eCOLORS>::Iterator( (int)(eCOLORS::Last ));
}

int main()
{
    Enum<eCOLORS> e; 
    // for( const auto x : Enum<eCOLORS>() )
    for( auto it=begin(e); 
        it!=end(e); ++it )
    {

    }
}
```

The errors are listed below

```
clang++ -g -std=c++0x \
    sandbox.cpp -o sandbox

clang: /mnt/home/foobar/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/Decl.cpp:1001: bool clang::NamedDecl::isCXXInstanceMember() const: Assertion `isCXXClassMember() && "checking whether non-member is instance member"' failed.
0  clang           0x0000000001aecc4f
1  clang           0x0000000001aed179
2  libpthread.so.0 0x00002aeeaeda1060
3  libc.so.6       0x00002aeeaf98b3a5 gsignal + 53
4  libc.so.6       0x00002aeeaf98eb0b abort + 379
5  libc.so.6       0x00002aeeaf983d4d __assert_fail + 221
6  clang           0x0000000000ed8f9e clang::NamedDecl::isCXXInstanceMember() const + 174
7  clang           0x0000000000a51095 clang::Sema::CheckQualifiedMemberReference(clang::Expr*, clang::QualType, clang::CXXScopeSpec const&, clang::LookupResult const&) + 213
8  clang           0x0000000000a55520 clang::Sema::BuildMemberReferenceExpr(clang::Expr*, clang::QualType, clang::SourceLocation, bool, clang::CXXScopeSpec const&, clang::SourceLocation, clang::NamedDecl*, clang::LookupResult&, clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo const*, bool) + 672
9  clang           0x0000000000a518d4 clang::Sema::BuildMemberReferenceExpr(clang::Expr*, clang::QualType, clang::SourceLocation, bool, clang::CXXScopeSpec&, clang::SourceLocation, clang::NamedDecl*, clang::DeclarationNameInfo const&, clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo const*) + 772
10 clang           0x0000000000b50378
11 clang           0x0000000000b58a19
12 clang           0x0000000000b56362
13 clang           0x0000000000b4e87b clang::Sema::SubstExpr(clang::Expr*, clang::MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList const&) + 75
14 clang           0x0000000000b64a69 clang::Sema::SubstInitializer(clang::Expr*, clang::MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList const&, bool) + 169
15 clang           0x0000000000b6d57f clang::Sema::InstantiateMemInitializers(clang::CXXConstructorDecl*, clang::CXXConstructorDecl const*, clang::MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList const&) + 1135
16 clang           0x0000000000b6cb13 clang::Sema::InstantiateFunctionDefinition(clang::SourceLocation, clang::FunctionDecl*, bool, bool) + 2307
17 clang           0x0000000000b6dadd clang::Sema::PerformPendingInstantiations(bool) + 461
18 clang           0x00000000008e0bb3 clang::Sema::ActOnEndOfTranslationUnit() + 419
19 clang           0x00000000008757d0 clang::Parser::ParseTopLevelDecl(clang::OpaquePtr<clang::DeclGroupRef>&) + 112
20 clang           0x00000000008727c6 clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool) + 326
21 clang           0x000000000075623e clang::CodeGenAction::ExecuteAction() + 958
22 clang           0x0000000000612f3d clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 957
23 clang           0x00000000005fb55a clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) + 3098
24 clang           0x00000000005f17ce cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 5918
25 clang           0x00000000005f7679 main + 729
26 libc.so.6       0x00002aeeaf97630d __libc_start_main + 237
27 clang           0x00000000005effe9
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/local/bin/clang -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name sandbox.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -g -resource-dir /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -I /home/kfeng/dev/pitbull/cpp/inc/ -I /home/kfeng/src/stlsoft/include/ -I /home/kfeng/src/gtest/include/ -I /home/kfeng/src/gmock/include/ -I /home/kfeng/src/pantheios/include/ -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++0x -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/kfeng/dev/pitbull/cpp/sbx -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 181 -mstackrealign -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/sandbox-0nnyL0.o -x c++ sandbox.cpp 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  sandbox.cpp:5:2: instantiating function definition 'Enum'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Aborted
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/sandbox-Fp11tf.ii
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/sandbox-Fp11tf.sh
```

Comment: Note: That is an internal compiler error. That is, the compiler crashed. That's a "bug in the compiler" error, not a "bug in your code" error.

Comment: @NicolBolas +1 ty for the verification - I've learned to never claim a compiler error unless I can verify with someone else.  I will file a bug report.

Comment: Note to self: Bugzilla Report 12106 filed

Comment: @kfmfe04: when the compiler produces a stack dump, you can safely assume there is an issue with the compiler. However malformed the input, no program worth its salt should crash on it. Of course, using the trunk and living on the bleeding edge, there is a chance you'll stumble on non-implemented sections or newly reworked ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles for me with the stable release of clang. Looks like it's a bug in trunk.

```
% clang --version
clang version 3.0 (tags/RELEASE_30/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
% clang++ -o test test.cc -std=c++0x
%
```

Comment: +1 ty for the sanity check – I will note your observation in a bugzilla filing to help them locate the bug.

Comment: seems like it's fixed on trunk now